# Pandas ffill() with average of before missing value and after missing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame and the requirement is to fill the NaN value in a row with by dividing sum of before missing value and after missing value by 3 and adding the result to the before missing value (This fills first Row Nan value). Second NaN is to be filled with sum of before missing value and after missing value by 3 (same as previous) but to add the result to the first filled NaN Value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1,np.nan,np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 11, 1,2,6, np.nan, np.nan, 15]})

and the expected result is:
```

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1,2,3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 1,2,6, 9, 12, 15]})

Comment: please show an example

Comment: You can use shift to get the forward and backward lag then average the results for forward fill.  The problem will be if you have multiple missing values before or after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is actually what [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) is doing by default (`method='linear'`):

```
df.interpolate()
```

Output:

```
     val
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    7.0
6    9.0
7   11.0
8    1.0
9    2.0
10   6.0
11   9.0
12  12.0
13  15.0
```